# Is there a way to change the sequence of value while inheriting selection field Odoo

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-15

I have a selection field and I want to inherit and update the selection field without overriding, here is what I am implementing.

Base field:

```
test_field = fields.Selection([ ('a', 'A'),('c', 'C'),],'Test Field')
```

The way I inherited

```
test_field = fields.Selection(selection_add=[('b', 'B')])
```

But this updates the field by updating the selection value in the end like this:

```
[('a', 'A'),('c', 'C'), ('b', 'B')]
```

however I want something like this:

```
[('a', 'A'),('b', 'B'), ('c', 'C')]
```

Just wondering if there is way to accomplish this without actually overriding the field. Any ideas or thoughts would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

From [class odoo.fields.Selection](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/fr/developer/reference/backend/orm.html#odoo.fields.Selection) documentation:

> or singletons (value,), where singleton values must appear in the overridden selection. The new values are inserted in an order that is consistent with the overridden selection

You can add the `('b', 'B')` pair before the singleton like following:

```
test_field = fields.Selection(selection_add=[('b', 'B'), ('c',)])
```